# Postgres BRIN index for time-series table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, index-tuning, time-series-database

I have multiple time-series tables with Pkey on `timestamp` column.

I'd like to test performance improvement if I change the index to be `BRIN` instead of `BTREE`.

Yet, I'd also like to have a UNIQUE constraint on the `timestamp` column (which as far as I know is based on `BTREE`).

What are my options?

- Should I add an additional `BRIN` index to `BTREE`? In this case which index will be chosen during searches / joins?
- Should I drop the pkey and add just the `UNIQUE` constraint? In this case how is it going to work?

My usage scenario is that I need to run FULL OUTER JOINs on a `timestamp` column to make queries from multiple tables all together and those queries sometimes can run for 30 minutes or more.

Comment: If you have a performance problem, you should describe what it is.  If you don't have a performance problem, what is the point of this?

Comment: Added the usage scenario

Comment: So your theory is that BRIN indexes on timestamps will somehow make your multiple full joins faster? It would probably be easier for you to just try that out, than waiting for someone on the internet to test that for you.

Comment: @mustaccio, I didn't ask somebody to test it for me. It'd be easier for everybody if every commenter would read the question - I asked how to properly implement it, if UNIQUE constraint is also required.

Comment: The performance impass come From the FULL OUTER JOINS,and if you do that m,ultiple times it egts worse each and every tme, so you shod take yoir query and restart new to see if you come up with a better solution

Comment: @nbk , I don't get he idea - if I separate it to multiple queries - I will still need to merge the result into a single time-series manually.

Comment: You have a timeseires and then LEFT JOIN all other subsselect will probably do the trick, as we don't know your schema and data and wanted result we can only speculate, but multiple FO´LOUTER JOIN seems tp be a bad idea and need a godd think about your design , seconed start from the result you need and go backwards till you reach your goal,

Comment: @nbk - I actually did something like this with GENERATE_SERIES of timestamps and later LEFT JOIN all others to it. Yet the performance of it was even less good than the FULL OUTER JOINs..... Not sure why

Comment: see wit explain what the database is actually doing doing, experiment with different combined keys and like i said may your design needs some rethinking

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You could go [here](https://dbfiddle.uk) and provide some sample tables and data so that we can see your scenario - the more information you provide, the better the answer(s) you will obtain! Use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) <your query>` to see what's going on - both with `BTREE` and `BRIN` - on the fiddle `SET `enable_seqscan OFF;` so the server will (hopefully) use an index instead of performing a full table scan on a small sample table.

Comment: The best indexing strategy cannot be derived from the sparse information in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BRIN index serves the same purpose as a B-tree index (only it is much smaller and less efficient for searches), so there is never a point in having both on the same column. Just don't create the BRIN index, it is superfluous.

PostgreSQL may still choose the BRIN index (if you perform range scans that result in many rows), but I don't think you will win a lot, and it is probably better to do without the maintenance cost for an additional index.

The primary key *is* a unique constraint (with an added `NOT NULL` constraint), so the second question is moot.

Comment: Just to summarize - you are saying that adding an extra BRIN index on `timestamp` will make Postgres use it, but the gain will not be significant (let's say above 10%) on time range operations, even though the BRIN index cost is really low. Is it correct?

Comment: I wouldn't be so bold as to name a percentage. I think it unlikely that the extra BRIN index will be a big win, because PostgreSQL can perform a bitmap index scan on a B-tree index. If I were you, I'd create a test setup with realistic data and try it myself. That's the only reliable way to arrive at a dependable figure.

Comment: appreciate your help!